# Does every minimally transitive subgroup of the symmetric group on a countably infinite set have finite point stabiliser?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $X$ be a countably infinite set with $x \in X$. Does every minimally transitive subgroup $H \leq$ Sym($X$) have $\vert \mbox{Stab}_{H}(x)\vert < \infty$?

A subgroup $H \leq$ Sym($X$) is *transitive* if for all $x,y \in X$ there exists $h \in H$ such that $h(x) = y$. A transitive subgroup $H \leq \mbox{Sym}(X)$ is *minimally transitive* if $K \leq H$ with $K$ transitive implies $K = H$.

For a subgroup $H \leq \mbox{Sym}(X)$ we define the *stabiliser* $\mbox{Stab}_{H}(x) = \{h \in H \vert h(x) = x\}$.

Trivial minimally transitive subgroups $H \leq \mbox{Sym}(X)$ are the regular subgroups, these are ones such that for all $x, y \in X$ there exists a unique element $h \in H$ such that $h(x) = y$. These are all realised by countable groups, i.e. if $G$ is a countable group then by Cayleys theorem there is a natural map $G \rightarrow Sym(G)$ given by the right regular action. These all have trivial stabilisers. However I was wondering if this extends to minimally transitive subgroups, the idea being that if you had an infinite stabiliser you should be able to drop to a smaller subgroup contained in that transitive subgroup cutting out some of the stabiliser.

I thought to construct a counter example by making a transitive subgroup with stabiliser $\mathbb{Z}$ however whenever I try to do this, I generate some junk in my stabiliser. E.g, $\langle (1,2), (2,3,4, \ldots) \rangle$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are examples of minimally transitive groups with infinite point stabilizers.

If $G$ is a countably infinite group and $x \in G$ has infinite order, then we could consider the permutation action of $G$ on the right cosets of the subgroup $\langle x \rangle$. A proper transitive subgroup would be a proper subgroup $H$ with $\langle x \rangle H = G$. If you chose $G$ to have no proper subgroups of finite index, then we would have $\langle x \rangle \cap H = 1$.

I am sure that there must be more elementary examples, but when you can't think of anything better, you can always try Tarski Monsters. There are such monsters in which all proper nontrivial subgroups are infinite cyclic (see discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2813243)). In such a group $H$ would be infinite cyclic.

Now Ito proved that, if a group $G$ is the product of two abelian subgroups, then $G$ is metabelian (i.e. solvable of derived length at most $2$). The proof of this result is clever but elementary. The original reference (in German for some reason) is N. Ito, Über das Produkt von zwei abelschen Gruppen, Math. Z. 62 (1955), 400-401.

Now it easy to see that noncyclic solvable groups have proper subgroups that are not infinite cyclic, so we have a contradiction. Hence $H$ cannot exist and $G$ is minimally transitive.

Comment: Hi Derek, I am a little confused by your answer, sorry. Let T be the Tarski monster who's proper subgroups are infinite cyclic subgroups. Then we fit your criteria perfectly. T is generated by x and y, any two non-commuting elements (Z(T) = 1, as T simple). Then T acts on the right cosets of <x> and the subgroup <y> has <x><y> = G and <x> intersect <y> = 1. This shows that T acting on the right cosets was not minimally transitive as the subgroup <y> is also transitive? I believe I have missed something here, should I be looking for a group where the condition <x> intersect H = 1 can't hold?

Comment: I have edited my answer to give more details. I would prefer to think of a more elementary example. The trouble with Tarski Monsters is that the proof of their existence is horrendously long and difficult.